# How to access a Linux encrypted external hard drive on Windows 7 Home Premium?

Tags: windows, linux, external-hard-drive, encryption

I encrypted my external hard drive using Linux Mint (Ubuntu) and password protected it. Now I can't access it on Windows 7 as it gives errors and won't mount. Is there a software that will allow me to read from this device? Note: I'm not sure exactly which algorithm was used to encrypt the drive but it was the standard option in Linux Mint (Ubuntu) and it sounded universal, but apparently not. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you boot the liveCD and mount the drive, then decrypt it?

Comment: No because you would need to reformat the drive to decrypt it, that or install Linux again and transfer all files to the computer and then reformat/decrypt it but I'm trying to avoid having to install Linux on any computers. Plus, it would be nice to keep the current encryption/password active on the drive while I use Windows.

Comment: you can actually mount any crypted drive within a live environment, given that the LiveCD supports cryptsetup. Assuming standard encrypion without keyfile and no lvm inside cryptdrive `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdxY crypt && mount /dev/mapper/crypt /mount/point` should work, just change the partition and mount target.

Comment: That is what I was referring to (above).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [FreeOTFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeOTFE)

I am pretty sure that Ubuntu / Mint uses dm-crypt with Luks and AES-Algorithm as standard for /home encryption as most modern CPUs support AES natively and thus it is very fast (faster than read/write of the harddrive).

FreeOTFE seems to be able to read all of the supported modes, so you might give it a shot. I never used it myself so no guarantee.

Comment: Thanks for updating your comment, I will check out FreeOTFE and let you know!